# Why must the tabhost id be an @android:id type?

Tags: android, layout

I always see the layout xml files use the @android:id instead of @+id to create a tabhost type, but why is it so? Same views like tabwidget and tabcontent and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `TabHost` and related are part of the `android` package, so you're specifying that you want to use the predefined Android's ID for those layouts. It's a matter of good practices when instantiating those objects.